# javascript for-loop in SQLite query

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have created a function that will return the string "path" from my DB.

```
    function getAudio(mid, cb) {
    //mid is an array containing the id to some multimedia files.
    for(i=0; i < mid.length; i++) {

        db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Multimedia WHERE Mid=' + mid[i] + ' AND Type=' + 2, [], function(tx, results) {    
                //type=2 is audio. (type=1 is picture file etc) There is only one audiofile in the array.
                    if(results.rows.length > 0) {
                        path = results.rows.item(0).Path; 
                        cb(path);
                    }
                }, errorCB);
        }, errorCBQuery);

    }//end for
}//end getAudio()
```

When I remove the for-loop, the query is successfull, when the for-loops is there,
errorCBQuery or errorCB is called.

Any Ideas on how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: lol that is just a typo :p
there has been plenty of removing and adding code the last hour.
My bad :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, thanks for notifying me about that. *edited* :)

Comment: You should use parameterized sql instead of using string concatenation, in order to protect yourself from SQL injection. Given the array argument you passed I guess it would look something like `tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Multimedia WHERE Mid=? AND Type=?', [mid[i], 2]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the classic closure problem. [`transaction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-database-transaction) is an *asynchronous* call, which means your loop completes before the function you pass in is triggered. The function has an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, not a copy of it as of when you called `transaction`. So each of those functions (you're generating one on each loop) is seeing `i == mid.length` and thus `mid[i]` is `undefined` and your SQL gets messed up.

What you need to do is have the callbacks close over another variable that won't change when the loop proceeds. The usual way to do that is to use a factory function:

```
function getAudio(mid, cb) {
    //mid is an array containing the id to some multimedia files.
    for(i=0; i < mid.length; i++) {

        db.transaction(makeTx(mid[i]), errorCBQuery);

    }//end for

    function makeTx(val) {
        return function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Multimedia WHERE Mid=' + val + ' AND Type=' + 2, [], function(tx, results) {    
            //type=2 is audio. (type=1 is picture file etc) There is only one audiofile in the array.
                if(results.rows.length > 0) {
                    path = results.rows.item(0).Path; 
                    cb(path);
                }
            }, errorCB);
        };
    }

}//end getAudio()
```

There, I'm passing `mid[i]` into the `makeTx` function, which *returns* the function that will get passed into `transaction`. The function we return closes over the `val` argument for the call to `makeTx` that created it, which doesn't change.

That's a *minimal* rewrite of the code; you can probably take it further. For example, see missingno's comment on the question re parameterized statements.

---

Side note: It doesn't look like you declare `i` or `path` anywhere. If that's really true, you're falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*. Recommend declaring them.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad: can't upvote before I got 15 in reputation. But I answered "yes" at "useful post" :)

Comment: @TorK: You can, however, *accept* answers (if you find them acceptable).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: aaah so that's what the symbol meant ^^ *done*
thanks again, guess I see you guys around ;)

Comment: Hi crowder, can you please suggest me how to resolve my problem, the link is as follows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199541/issue-with-loop-the-select-query-in-sqlite/